# How To Make The Background Transparent?

Tags: fusioncharts

I'm new to FusionCharts. How to make the below background marked with a red rectangle transparent? Currently all I can do is to make outer background transparent , but the central part isn't.

And how to customize font color?
 my code :

```
FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');
                                            var chart = new FusionCharts("../content/charts/MultiAxisLine.swf", "ChartId", "740", "231", "0", "0");
                                            chart.setDataXML("<chart  bgAlpha='0,0' caption='' showBorder='0' lineThickness='1' showValues='0' formatNumberScale='0' labelDisplay='ROTATE' slantLabels='1' rotateValues='1'  borderThickness='0' alternateHGridColor='FCB541' alternateHGridAlpha='20' divLineColor='FCB541' divLineAlpha='50' canvasBorderColor='666666' baseFontColor='3E3E3F'><categories><category label='Oct10'/><category label='Nov10'/><category label='Dec10'/><category label='Jan11'/><category label='Feb11'/><category label='Mar11'/><category label='Apr11'/><category label='May11'/><category label='Jun11'/><category label='Jul11'/><category label='Aug11'/><category label='Sep11'/></categories><axis title='MAPE' titlePos='left' tickWidth='10' divlineisdashed='1' numberSuffix='%' color='1D8BD1'> <dataset seriesName='MAPE %' color='1D8BD1' anchorBorderColor='1D8BD1' anchorBgColor='1D8BD1'><set  value='83'/><set  value='68'/><set  value='63'/><set  value='68'/><set  value='81'/><set  value='95'/><set  value='67'/><set  value='72'/><set  value='86'/><set  value='69'/><set  value='86'/><set  value='69'/></dataset></axis><axis title='MAD' titlePos='left' tickWidth='10' divlineisdashed='1' color='F1683C'> <dataset seriesName='MAD' color='F1683C' anchorBorderColor='F1683C' anchorBgColor='F1683C'> <set  value='5'/><set  value='4'/><set  value='3'/><set  value='4'/><set  value='7'/><set  value='9'/><set  value='6'/><set  value='4'/><set  value='4'/><set  value='7'/><set  value='7'/><set  value='4'/></dataset></axis><axis title='RMSE'  titlepos='RIGHT' axisOnLeft='0'  tickWidth='10' divlineisdashed='1' color='2AD62A'> <dataset seriesName='RMSE' color='2AD62A' anchorBorderColor='2AD62A' anchorBgColor='2AD62A'><set  value='11'/><set  value='10'/><set  value='10'/><set  value='13'/><set  value='20'/><set  value='26'/><set  value='18'/><set  value='10'/><set  value='10'/><set  value='24'/><set  value='23'/><set  value='15'/> </dataset> </axis></chart>");
                                            chart.setTransparent(true)
                                            chart.render("chartdiv1");
```

the snapshot is at http://t1.qpic.cn/mblogpic/061381e1504222d57828/2000.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding `canvasBgAlpha='0'` and `legendBgAlpha='0'` in `<chart>` element.